# how to display form data in the same page after submit in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, frontend, react-forms

i want to dispaly data only after submit the form. But using this code, the data is shown without submit. how to modify the code

```
    import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState({ paragraph: "" })
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setData({
      ...data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
console.log(e.target.value)
  }

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    
    console.log(data)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <label>Enter the paragraph</label>
        <textarea name="paragraph" type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={data.paragraph} rows={3} cols={30}/>
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
      <p>{data.paragraph}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to `<p>{data.paragraph}</p>`

If you would like it to not be shown until the submit you are going to have to use a different variable.

You are using `data.paragraph` for the textarea input, so whenever you write it will also render below